# Find in Path. Как исключить файлы типа R.java из поиска?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Андроид Студио.

Поиск: **Find in Path**

Как исключить файлы типа R.java из поиска?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кроме ответа выше вы можете воспользоваться быстрым фильтром по маске:

[image: scrn]

Ставите отметку *File mask:* и пишите маску - *!R.java* - исключить из поиска файл R.java

Для быстрого ввода работает автозаполнение:

[image: scrn]

Comment: Pavlofff! Спасибо! Такое решение многому учит!!! )

Comment: А можно исключить два вида файлов так: !R.java&&!*.mp3  ?

Comment: через запятую: `!R.java, !*.mp3`

Comment: Pavlofff! Огромное спасибо! Дай Бог тебе здоровья!

Answer (score 7):

Создать свою область поиска можно следующим образом.

1. `File | Settings | Appearance and Behavior | Scopes` for Windows and Linux

   `IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences | Appearance and Behavior | Scopes` for macOS
2. Выбрать `+` (добавить область)(local|shared)
3. В поле Имя введите название области, например `NotRjava`
4. В поле паттерн введите `!file:*/R.java`
5. Жмем `OK`
6. `Ctrl+Shift+F` с опцией scope выбираете из выпадающего списка `NotRjava`

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scopes.html

Comment: TimurVI! Спасибо!... Но офигеть! Такое простое (причем очевидное, популярное) исключение... и такие невероятные навороты надо сделать!... Сырая студия еще весьма! ) Сырая...

Comment: @user вы всегда можете использовать альтернативные среды разработки и в полной мере проникнуться их "сухостью". Ну а серьезно, если вам что то вдруг понадобилось, вовсе не значит, что это надо всем и без этого продукт сырой - если учитывать возможные хотелки каждого, то пользоваться "сухим" продуктом будет невозможно. Именно поэтому каждый может настроить под себя всего за несколько кликов мыши.