# Как удобнее искать во всех исходниках (*.java) всех проектов сразу? (например, чтобы обновить кусок кода во всех проектах)

Tags: android-studio, поиск, редактор

В данный момент ищу и правлю с помощью Nodepad++ (но не нравится то, что не могу отфильтровать файлы типа R.java и они попадают в выдачу)

Конечно, все не нужные папки (файлы) можно сделать невидимыми предварительно, а потом видимыми снова, но в моем случае это будет не реально много волокиты.

Или как искать только в папках по маске?

Или какой может быть другой использовать редактор, поисковик, чтобы мог с папками по маске работать (искать/исключать папки по маске) И еще бы желательно, чтобы поиск в комментариях мог бы исключать)

P.S. Работаю в Андроид Студио. Может там все это можно сделать, одновременно в десяти проектах

Спасибо

Comment: [Find in Path. Как исключить файлы типа R.java из поиска?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/778477/find-in-path-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-r-java-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0/778492#778492)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Android Studio вы можете использовать инструмент *Find in Path* для поиска или *Replace in Path* для автоматической замены кода так же, как в ответах на ваш [прошлый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778477/177345), указав в качестве места поиска папку со всеми проектами (секция Directory под строкой поиска):

[image: scrn]

на скриншоте поиск ведется по папке *D:\Projects*, которая содержит все мои проекты. Каждый найденный метод `setContentView()` относится к разным проектам.

Comment: Pavloff! Огромное спасибо! За столь ценный совет!!!